# When does a faithful representation remain faithful on a quotient representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose I have a faithful complex representation of some finite group $(V,\pi)$. I can show that whenever this representation contains the trivial representation $(\mathbb{C}v,1)$, so that as a module $V \cong \mathbb{C}v\oplus U$, then I get a faithful quotient representation $(U\cong V/\mathbb{C}v,\overline{\pi})$.  So, for any subspace $S \subseteq V$ where $G$ acts trivially I can iterate this and get a faithful representation on the quotient space $V/S$.  I want to know what kind of converse there is to this statement:

If A faithful representation $V$ of $G$ has a subrepresentation $U$, and the representation on $V/U$ remains faithful, must $G$ act trivially on $U$?  If not can we say anything about the subrepresentation $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any non-trivial but highly reducible representation of a simple group. They are all faithful (not much of a choice for kernel, so forced to be faithful!) and so quotienting by subrepresentation again gives a faithful representation.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful example.